# Update contacts from address book for the contacts updated while the app was terminated

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook

I have used `AddressBook` to fetch contacts and store it in `Core Data`. I also register for `ExternalCallBack` which is working perfectly fine.

The problem is that I want to update contacts in `CoreData` when the app becomes active if any contact is updated in `AddressBook` while the app was in background(inactive) or closed(terminated).

I have searched for the solution but failed to find one. I don't know if it is possible with existing frameworks or not.

Updating contact information is important for the application.

So please suggest me if there is any method to solve this problem or any other idea or trick that might help to work other way around.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Register for Notification "CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification" available in contacts framework. if Any change made in addressBook it will notify you even if app is in background.

Comment: Sorry. The question is updated. I wanted to update even if the app is inactive or closed. I did not mention that first time.

Comment: @MananDevani did you find a solution?

Comment: @Ignor Khomenko: No, I was unable to find the solution for our problem.